# ASP.NET Core MVC project InvalidOperationException error

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC CRUD project in Visual Studio. But when I run the project, I get an error. There isn't error in project but it can not find `Index.cshtml` folders. I have index folders in the project. What can I do fix the error ?

The error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
>
> /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable originalLocations)
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
>
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
> /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable originalLocations)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|30_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please check for spelling errors and remember that the file name maybe case sensitive.